# How much must be taken from each slice of a pie cut into 3rds to be able to share equally between 4 people

Tags: fractions

Theoretically, if $3$ people were to split a pie evenly amongst themselves, only to have a $4$th person join them, how much or what fraction of each of their $\frac{1}{3}$ slices must be taken and given to the $4$th person, so that everyone has an equal amount of pie. I know it's possible to split each $\frac{1}{3}$ slice into quarters and divide the $12$ resulting slices evenly, but I don't want that answer. I'm wondering what fraction would be needed from each $\frac{1}{3}$ slice, ie, what fraction of $\frac{1}{3}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 people each would have 4/12 of the pie while 4 people would each have 3/12 of the pie.  3/12 is 3/4 of 4/12, and that's the amount each of the original three people gets to keep, which means each of the original three people must give the fourth person 1/12 of the pie.  1/12 is 1/4 of 4/12, so each of the original three people must give away 1/4 of their original share of the pie to the new person.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now